# How to set size of a cell of a collection view from code in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

The following code says gives error that my class "MainVC" cannot inherit from UICollectionViewFlowLayout , also sizeForItemAt does not auto complete, am I missing something? I need to create a cell of a size half the width of a screen

```
extension HomeVC:UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int { return subjectList.count }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "subject", for: indexPath) as! SubjectCell
        let subject = subjectList[indexPath.row]as Subjects
        cell.subject = subject
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2, height: 100.0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conform to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` instead of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

Comment: I believe it's "Conforming delegate" `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout `, rather than "Inherit"